# Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function and there are no functions with the same name

Tags: javascript

(I've looked everywhere and still can't find anything, sorry if its a duplicate.)

When ever I try to call lifh(); it keeps giving me the error: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function - on chrome's console

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>-- snip --</title>
    <style>
        -- snipped css code --
    </style>
    <script>
        lifh = function() {
            var lif = document.getElementById("left");
            lif.innerHTML("<iframe id='iframe_left' src='home.html'></iframe>");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="leftIFrameControls">
        <input id="leftIFrameHomeBtn" type="button" value="Home" onClick="lifh();" />
    </div>
    <div id="rightIFrameControls">
        <input id="rightIFrameHomeBtn" type="button" value="Home" onClick="rightIFrameHome()" /><a href="javascript:leftIFrameHome()">test</a>http://vezg.com/browse.php?u=Oi8vd3d3LnBsYW5ldG1pbmVjcmFmdC5jb20v&b=5
    </div>
    <div id="left"><iframe id='iframe_left' src='home.html'></iframe></div>
    <div id="right"><iframe id='iframe_right' src='home.html'></iframe></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it should be

```
        lif.innerHTML = "<iframe id='iframe_left' src='home.html'></iframe>";
```

`innerHTML` is a property, not a function.

Comment: Thank you! It works! EDIT: Only 4 minutes till I can set it as the answer tho -_-

Answer (score 1):

Go for below code it works

```
lif.innerHTML = "<iframe id='iframe_left' src='home.html'></iframe>";
```